# MySQL select column_names of table which has a particular value for a given row

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'forms' with the following columns:
id, name, desc, exporter1, exporter2 ,exporter3

My intention is to get the column names if the values for those columns are equal to a particular value.

Consider the following rows in the 'forms' table,

1, test1, testdesc, 1,0,1

2, test2, testdesc, 1,1,1

3, test3, testdesc, 0,1,0

so the query should return me the column names with values equal to '1'.

For the first row the return value should be - "exporter1, exporter3".

For the second row - "exporter1, exporter2, exporter3".

For the third row - "exporter2".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: names with values equal to '1'?

Comment: @Code-Monk yes the names of the columns whose corresponding values for the rows is 1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299195/mysql-select-column-name-as-field If I go with the solution provided in this link, the query becomes lengthier. Is there any alternate solution? @Deep we are planning to optimize the table. For the time being, we would like to write a query to achieve the above result.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a Query from information Schema like this with all fields you want

```
SELECT
id, 
CONCAT_ws (',',
  IF ( exporter1 = 1, 'exporter1',NULL),
  IF ( exporter2 = 1, 'exporter2',NULL),
  IF ( exporter2 = 3, 'exporter3',NULL)
)
FROM forms;
```

Comment: This is cool :) Thanks. But is there a way to get the column name without mentioning it explicitly? From your answer, I can see that we have to explicitly return the value like 'exporter1' if the condition meets. Is there a way to return the column name as such like below:

`SELECT
id, 
CONCAT_ws (',',
  IF ( exporter1 = 1, COLUMN_NAME,NULL),
  IF ( exporter2 = 1, COLUMN_NAME,NULL),
  IF ( exporter2 = 3, COLUMN_NAME,NULL)
)
FROM forms;`

Return all column names whose value for the row is equal to 1 without we ourselves mentioning the column_names to return.